# How do i convert TLE files to csv using python?

Tags: python-3.x

I could not find how to convert TLE files into csv using python and i need to perform some calculation for the TLE files however i cannot read data elements, how do i segregate the TLE files? It would be easier to convert to CSV file and then i can perform some calculation but don't know how to convert to csv file

I thought it would be initially a text file however it is a little different than text file. I have never worked with TLE files so it would be helpful if someone knows how to convert a large TLE files to csv file

Comment: TLE being [two-line element set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set#:~:text=A%20two%2Dline%20element%20set,point%20in%20time%2C%20the%20epoch.) for earth-orbiting objects? Maybe something like pyorbital would do it. But the recipe for reading may be straight-forward. The link suggests a tittle line and 2 lines for each point in the file. Maybe post the first dozen or so lines of the file as an example?